# plotly choropleth incomplete display

Tags: plotly

In this code I want to plot a choropleth with fips.

```
fips_abs_err = pd.DataFrame(columns=['fips', 'Yield'])
fips_abs_err = fips_abs_err.append({'fips': '17001', 'Yield': 1}, ignore_index=True)
fig = px.choropleth(fips_abs_err, 
                    # geojson=counties, 
                    locations='fips', 
                    color='Yield',
                    color_continuous_scale="ylorrd",
                    # range_color=(0,8),
                    scope="usa",
                    labels={'1':'2 3'}
                    )
        
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
        
output_path = ""
fig.write_image(output_path, scale=5)
```

And the result is like this:

[image]

but it only shows a few states, I want a map with the whole US states. like this:
[image]

Could you tell me what argument should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling plotly to zoom in to fit to 'locations' with:

```
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
```

Remove that and the whole USA will stay in view.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

fips_abs_err = pd.DataFrame([{'fips': '17001', 'Yield': 1}])

fig = px.choropleth(fips_abs_err,
                    locations='fips',
                    color='Yield',
                    color_continuous_scale="ylorrd",
                    scope="usa",
                    labels={'1':'2 3'}
                    )

# fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)

output_path = "test.png"
fig.write_image(output_path, scale=5)
```

[image]